# Join Multiple table in sequelize with nested reationship

Tags: sequelize.js

I have tried to join three table with following nested relationship

my Models are,
tbl1:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define('tbl1', {
entityid: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},
lastname: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: true
},
firstname: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false
},
middlename: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: true
},
salutation: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false
},
gender: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false
},
contactno: {
  type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
  allowNull: false
},
email: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false
},
dob: {
  type: DataTypes.DATE, 
  allowNull: false,
},
doj: {
  type: DataTypes.DATE,
  allowNull: false,
},
dot: {
  type: DataTypes.DATE,
  allowNull: true
},
entitystatus: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: true
},
panno: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false
},
designation: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false
},
department: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false
},
location: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: true
},
maritalstatus: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false
}
}, {
tableName: 'tbl1',
freezeTableName: true
});
};
```

tbl2:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define('tbl2', {
decid: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},
tbl1Entityid: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  references: {
    model: 'tbl1',
    key: 'entityid'
  }
},
status: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  references: {
    model: 'cfg_codevalue',
    key: 'codevalueid'
  }
},
amountinvested: {
  type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
  allowNull: false
}
}, {
tableName: 'tbl2',
freezeTableName: true
});
};
```

tbl3 :

```
 module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
 return sequelize.define('tbl3', {
 detailid: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
 },
 tbl2Decid : {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  references: {
    model: 'tbl2',
    key: 'decid'
  }
 },
 sectionid: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  references: {
    model: 'tbl4',
    key: 'sectionid'
  }
 },
 tbl1Entityid: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  references: {
    model: 'tbl1',
    key: 'entityid'
  }
 },
 investmentid: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false
 },
 noteid: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  references: {
    model: 'txn_note',
    key: 'noteid'
  }
 },
 amount: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false
},
}, {
tableName: 'tbl3',
freezeTableName: true
});
};
```

and here is the relationship:

```
 tbl1.hasOne(tbl2);
 tbl2.belongsTo(tbl1);
 tbl2.hasMany(tbl3);
 tbl3.belongsTo(tbl2);

 tbl1.find({
        where: {email:"abc@abc.com"},
        include: [{
            model: tbl2,                
            include: [{
                model: tbl3,
            }]
        }]
    }).success(function(result) {
        callback(result);
    }).failure(function(error) {
        callback(error);
    });
```

it is not showing multiple rows from tbl3 that are related with tbl2.I also tried inner join with required but it is also showing same result

Comment: Can you post your model files?

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying to recreate the issue but unfortunately I couldn't. The join works just fine. Here's the model files I was using to test the issue.

models/tbl1.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize.define('tbl1', {
    entityid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    firstname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    middlename: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    salutation: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    },
    contactno: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: true
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    dob: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    doj: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    dot: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true
    },
    entitystatus: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    },
    panno: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    designation: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    department: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    },
    location: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    },
    maritalstatus: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'tbl1',
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: models => {
            models.tbl1.hasOne(models.tbl2, {
                foreignKey: 'tbl1Entityid'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

models/tbl2.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize.define('tbl2', {
    decid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    tbl1Entityid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    status: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    amountinvested: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'tbl2',
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: models => {
            models.tbl2.belongsTo(models.tbl1, {
                foreignKey: 'tbl1Entityid'
            });
            models.tbl2.hasMany(models.tbl3, {
                foreignKey: 'tbl2Decid'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

models/tbl3.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize.define('tbl3', {
    detailid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    tbl2Decid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    sectionid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    investmentid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    noteid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    amount: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'tbl3',
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: models => {
            models.tbl3.belongsTo(models.tbl2, {
                foreignKey: 'tbl2Decid'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Note: I intentionally changed some fields to allow null value to make testing easier.

**UPDATE**: Here's the main code I used to test the code.

app.js

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    path = require('path'),
    moment = require('moment'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    sequelize = new(require('sequelize-values')())('postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/development', {
        logging: console.log,
        native: false,
        pool: {
            maxConnections: 5,
            maxIdleTime: 3000
        },
        ssl: false,
        timezone: '+07:00'
    }),
    models = require('./models')(sequelize);

sequelize.sync().then(() => Promise.join(

    models.tbl1.upsert({
        entityid: 1,
        lastname: 'GHI',
        firstname: 'ABC',
        middlename: 'DEF',
        salutation: 'Mr.',
        contactno: '123456',
        email: 'abc@abc.com',
        dob: moment('12-12-1995', 'DD-MM-YYYY').format()
    }),
    models.tbl1.upsert({
        entityid: 2,
        lastname: 'Doe',
        firstname: 'Jane',
        middlename: 'Example',
        salutation: 'Ms.',
        contactno: '987654',
        email: 'jane.doe@example.com',
        dob: moment('01-04-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY').format()
    }),

    models.tbl2.upsert({
        decid: 1,
        tbl1Entityid: 1,
        status: 1,
        amountinvested: 123456789
    }),
    models.tbl2.upsert({
        decid: 2,
        tbl1Entityid: 2,
        status: 3,
        amountinvested: 987654321
    }),

    models.tbl3.upsert({
        detailid: 1,
        tbl2Decid: 1,
        sectionid: 50,
        investmentid: 60,
        noteid: 70,
        amount: 80
    }),
    models.tbl3.upsert({
        detailid: 2,
        tbl2Decid: 1,
        sectionid: 150,
        investmentid: 160,
        noteid: 170,
        amount: 180
    }),
    models.tbl3.upsert({
        detailid: 3,
        tbl2Decid: 2,
        sectionid: 250,
        investmentid: 260,
        noteid: 270,
        amount: 280
    })

)).then(() => models.tbl1.findOne({
    where: {
        email: 'abc@abc.com'
    },
    include: [{
        model: models.tbl2,
        include: [{
            model: models.tbl3,
        }]
    }]
})).then(result => {
    console.log(result.getValues());
});
```

models/index.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

module.exports = sequelize => {
    var models = {};

    fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== 'index.js');
    }).forEach(file => {
        var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
        models[model.name] = model;
    });

    Object.keys(models).forEach(modelName => {
        if ('associate' in models[modelName]) {
            models[modelName].associate(models);
        }
    });

    return models;
};
```

Comment: it is also give same result as my way

Comment: can you send me JSON output of above that you had done